# Uso de comillas simples o dobles en una cadena de texto

Tags: javascript

¿qué diferencias hay al utilizar comillas simples o dobles para cadenas de de texto en JavaScript?

```
 var daw = "Desarrollo de aplicaciones web";
 var dam = 'Desarrollo de aplicaciones multiplataforma';
```

Comment: Cuestión de gustos, no existe diferencia alguna entre usar comillas dobles o sencillas

Comment: Nop, no existe diferencia alguna, simplemente depende que tipo de caracteres desees almacenar en ésta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es un tema de gustos, puesto que no hay diferencia en significado. **Douglas Crockford**, unos de los más conocidos *gurús* de Javascript y desarrollador de JSLint, prefiere el uso de comillas dobles. Pero a muchos desarrolladores les parece más cómodo lo contrario.

### Comillas Dobles:

**Pros**:

- Es lo que usa la notación JSON, con lo que muchos lo prefieren por familiaridad/homogeneidad:

  `var obj={ "clave": "valor", "otra clave": 0};`
- Los anglosajones encuentran cómodo no tener que "escapar" los apóstrofes al usar el inglés:

  `var text="don't escape this"`.

**Contras**:

- Precisamente al intentar crear un JSON, tienes que escapar las comillas dobles:

  `var json="{\"clave\": 0}";`
- Lo mismo pasa al querer generar HTML:

  `var input="<input name=\"nombre\"/>";`

### Comillas Simples:

Invierte los pros y contras de las simples.

Personalmente uso siempre comillas simples, porque rara vez las uso como parte de mis textos, y dejo las dobles para el código HTML y JSON<sup>1</sup>, pero tienes que hacer lo que encuentres más cómodo.

En un proyecto en el que estés trabajando con otros desarrolladores aconsejo crear un documento que sea el libro de estilo del proyecto (si es que no existe ya, muchas empresas lo tienen definido a nivel corporativo) donde se establezca qué tipo de comillas se van a usar, el tipo de sangrado (tabulación o espaciado y en qué cantidad), el tipo de comentarios a usar, la longitud máxima de una línea de código... etc. para tener un código homogéneo.

<sup>1</sup> Nunca está de mas recalcar que no existe el concepto de "objeto JSON", hay objetos Javascript y strings en formato/notación JSON que representan a un objeto. "Un JSON" es un string del que se puede obtener un objeto Javascript mediante JSON.parse.

### Comillas simples inversas:

Las últimas en llegar a Javascript son las comillas para *string templates*:

```js
const respuesta= 42
const texto = `The Answer to
the Ultimate Question of Life,
The Universe,
and Everything is: ${respuesta}`;

console.log(texto);
```

Tienen características especiales que no tienen las comillas simples o las comillas dobles, como ser multilínea o aceptar parámetros con el formato `${valor}`.

Comment: Y que hay del tercer tipo de comillas en Javascript? justo esta: `

Answer (score 5):

No hay diferencia.

Pero si depende del uso que le quieras dar a la cadena.

Si ésta debe contener dobles comillas, entonces tienes que usar comillas simples

```js
 var comillasDobles = 'contiene "dobles comillas" sin problemas';
 console.log(comillasDobles)
```

y al revés

```js
 var comillasSimples= "contiene 'simples comillas' sin problemas";
 console.log(comillasSimples);
```

ahora si por alguna razon tienes una variables puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var texto = "pregunta";
var comillaDoble =`mi texto en comilla Doble es "${texto}"`;
var comillaSimple =`mi texto en comilla Simple  es '${texto}'`;
console.log(comillaDoble);
console.log(comillaSimple);
```

Answer (score 5):

Es indistinto el uso de comillas dobles o simples.

Hay que considerar que si se usan un tipo de comillas y se quiere reutilizarlas dentro de la cadena, estas deben ir con el símbolo de escape:

```
var cadena = "La siguiente \"palabra\" estaba entre comillas dobles y 'esta' con comillas simples.";
```