# Separar comilla simple en String JS

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo una cadena así:

```
var cadena = '<form name="name" th:action=" 'ERROR' ">';
```

Tengo unas comillas simples dentro de la cadena y es lo que limita el inicio y el fin, ¿cómo puedo hacer para incluir los caracteres de escape como parte de la cadena ?

Un saludo.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109334/uso-de-comillas-simples-o-dobles-en-una-cadena-de-texto/109347#109347

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para escapar tus comillas simples tendrás que escaparlas con `\`. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
var cadena = '\'tu contenido\'';
```

Comment: Buenas @valerogarte , la respuesta está bien, simplemente la he editado para corregirla un poco en cuanto a que las partes de código deben ir con su formato propio y  hacerla más fácil de leer, por lo demás está bien.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar los template strings para incluir las comillas simples, ademas de tener otras funcionalidades como cadenas de texto de más de una linea, se utilizan con los backtips o tilde invertida `, dejo un link para que puedas aprender mas de ello https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

```
    var cadena = `''`
```