# Imprimir cadena de texto de Javascript en html

Tags: javascript, html

tengo este problema: 
Defino una cadena de texto en js:

```
htmo = "";
html += "<table class=  "+" table table-responsive table-bordered";
```

pero el navegador lo interpreta de la siguiente

```
<table class="table" table-responsive="" table-bordered="">
```

me prodian decir como concateno la cadena de tal manera que lo interprete bien el navegador(USO FIREFOX)
Gracias

Comment: En codigo js   
html = "";
html += "<table class=  "+" table table-responsive table-bordered";
interpretado por el navegador
<table class="table" table-responsive="" table-bordered="">

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes concatenar, pero los navegadores ya soportan hacerlo con comillas invertidas (``), osea: `Esto es lo que quiero concatenar ${aqui las variables} y funciona...` Todo dentro de las comillas.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109334/uso-de-comillas-simples-o-dobles-en-una-cadena-de-texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado esta concatenación y parece que el resultado es lo que buscas. Pruébalo:

```
html = "";
 html += "<table class='table table-responsive table-bordered'>";
```

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, me ha funcionado de maravilla